# Add a price to a string array

Tags: android, string, arrays

So i have a string array full of different vodkas, what i want to do is attach a price to each     vodka (string) in the array so that i can display the vodka along with its price on the screen, i also want to use this to filter out higher price or lower price vodkas depending on the users input.
Here is an example array:

```
    public static final String[] Vodka = {"Absolut Vodka","Finlandia","Ketel One","Polmos Krakow","Skyy","Smirnoff Vodka",
    "Stolichnaya","Fleischmann's","Gilbey's","Wolfschmitt","Five-O-Clock", "Grey Goose",};
```

Thanks in advance everyone!

=================================

Here is a bit of code i was trying out thank to mike!

```
if(Price != 0){ 
    for (com.famousmods.what.should.i.drink.VodkaList.Vodka vodka : vl.vodkaList){ 
        // Set vodka brand final 
        TextView text21 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display2); 
        test = random.next(vodka.getPrice() <= Price); 
        text21.setText(test); 
    } 
}
```

The Price is the max amount that the user inputs, it a double, what i was trying to do with that piece of code was randomly get a drink that is less than the price that is inputted. (it was just a shot in the dark really)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make a custom class "Vodka" that has 2 fields: name and price.  Then make a "VodkaList" class that encapsulates the "Vodka" class and includes an `ArrayList<Vodka>`  This keeps everything well organized.

So, for example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class VodkaList {

    public class Vodka {

        String name;
        double price; 

        public Vodka(String name, double price) {
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public double getPrice() {
            return this.price;
        }

        public void setPrice(double price) {
            this.price = price;
        }


    }

    public ArrayList<Vodka> vodkaList;

    public VodkaList() {
        this.vodkaList = new ArrayList<Vodka>();

        // here's where you can hard-code the list of Vodkas
        vodkaList.add(new Vodka("Absolut Vodka", 15.75));
        vodkaList.add(new Vodka("Findlandia", 10.25));
        // and repeat until you've hard-coded them all
    }


}
```

By using a custom class, you can alter the name/price of Vodka at any time, not worry about keeping track of array indices, and easily search the list for the names/prices you want.

Here's what you'll put in your main activity to initialize your VodkaList:

```
VodkaList vl = new VodkaList();
```

Want to loop through the list and see which Vodkas you put in?

```
for (Vodka vodka : vl.vodkaList)
    Log.i("Vodka", "Name = " + vodka.name + ", Price = " + vodka.price);
```

Let's explore a sample scenario (to address the issue in your problem statement). Let's say the user enters "10" for the highest price he/she will pay.

```
for (Vodka vodka : vl.vodkaList) {
    if (vodka.getPrice() < 10)
        ; // the price is good! the user wants it.  show them it
    else
        ; // too expensive for the user.. don't show it
}
```

This class will make this sort of activity easy!

Tell me if that works.  If not, I'll offer more suggestions.

**EDIT:**

```
    Random random = new Random();
    boolean available = false;

    for (Vodka v : vodkaList) {
        if (v.price <= Price)
            available = true;
    }

    TextView text21 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display2);

    if (available) {
        // There exists at least one Vodka lower than the user's price
        int randomIndex = -1;
        while (true) {
            randomIndex = random.nextInt(vodkaList.size());
            Vodka v = vodkaList.get(randomIndex);
            if (v.price <= Price) {
                // We have a match!  Display it to the user
                text21.setText(v.name);
                break;
            }
            // If we got here, there's no match.. loop again!

        }
    } else {
        // No vodka exists unders the users price! Can't display anything
    }
```

Comment: This may sound like a dumb question but please bare with me, do i have to add a new vodka from the main activity? Can i just put them into the class manually so i dont have to fill up my activity page?

Comment: From where do you want to put them?  Another activity?  Or do you want to hardcode all of them?

Comment: Check out my edit to my answer, as well as the new function as the bottom of the Vodka class.

Comment: Im having trouble initializing the arraylist in my main activity when i call "vodkaList = Vodka.initVodkaList(vodkaList); " I get the error "The method initVodkaList(ArrayList<Vodka>) is undefined for the type Boolean" Do you have any kind of instant messaging so that i could get some easier help from you?

Comment: It's not entirely efficient, but I tested it and it's working for me.  I changed the entire answer's code, so try that now.  The only annoying bit is typing "vl.vodkaList", rather than just a single variable (ie "vodkaList") - however, it'll still work.

Comment: It's not entirely efficient, but I tested it and it's working for me. I changed the entire answer's code, so try that now. The only annoying bit is typing "vl.vodkaList", rather than just a single variable (ie "vodkaList") - however, it'll still work.  Also, don't forget to accept the answer if it works for you :).

Comment: @Hockeyman271 - don't forget to accept this answer if it worked for you :).

Comment: sorry i was away for the weekend, im running into another issue (I know im a huge pain in the ass i apologize)

Comment: (Continued)  I want to display a random drink with a price below what the user sets so i tried this  `if(Price != 0){
                  for (com.famousmods.what.should.i.drink.VodkaList.Vodka vodka : vl.vodkaList){
                   // Set vodka brand
                   final TextView text21 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display2);
                         test = random.next(vodka.getPrice() <= Price);
                         text21.setText(array_city.Vodka[randomIndex]);
                  }
                 }`   But i am getting an error?

Comment: (Changed a piece of the code, still doesnt work )  if(Price != 0){ for (com.famousmods.what.should.i.drink.VodkaList.Vodka vodka : vl.vodkaList){ // Set vodka brand final TextView text21 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display2); test = random.next(vodka.getPrice() <= Price); text21.setText(test); } }

Comment: The code is a bit hard to read here - would you mind editing it to the bottom of your answer?  Also, what is `random.next(vodka.getPrice <= Price)`?  And what is `Price`?  And don't worry, you're not a pain at all :) I love to help.

Comment: Try the code I added to the **Edit:** section of my answer.  Note: you should make sure you understand exactly what's going on here (not just copy and pasting it).  I haven't tested it, but it seems clean.

Comment: Hello again, @Hockeyman271.  Don't forget to accept the answer that helped you :).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use two-dimensional Array instead:

```
public static final String[][] drinks= { 
          {"Absolut Vodka", "10.0"}, {"Finlandia", "15.0"}
          {"Ketel One", "10.0"}, {"Stolichnaya", "15.0"}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Vodka
{
  private String name;
  private int price;

  public Vodka() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   }
   public void setName(String name)
   {
     this.name=name;
   }
   public void setPrice(int price)
   {
    this.price=price;
   }

   public String getName()
   {
    return this.name;
   }
   public int getPrice()
   {
    return this.price;
   }

}
```

In your activity,

```
List<Vodka> myList = new ArrayList<Vodka> ();
      Vodka vodk = new Vodka();
      vodk.setName("Smirnoff");
      vodk.setPrice(10);

      myList.add(vodk);
```

To retrieve data:

```
String name = myList.get(0).getName();
 int price = myList.get(0).getPrice();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use some **OOP concept, Collections** classes will also help you a lot.

```
package com.mac.demo;

import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class SortBean {
public String name;
public double price;

SortBean(String name, Double price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SortBean sb1 = new SortBean("Absolut Vodka", 20.0);
    SortBean sb2 = new SortBean("Finlandia", 30.0);
    SortBean sb3 = new SortBean("Ketel One", 80.0);

    SortedMap<Double, SortBean> sMap = new TreeMap<Double, SortBean>();
     // IF YOU WANT TO SORT IN REVERSE ORDER 
    //SortedMap<Double, SortBean> sMap = new TreeMap<Double, SortBean>(Collections.reverseOrder());

    sMap.put(sb1.price, sb1);
    sMap.put(sb2.price, sb2);
    sMap.put(sb3.price, sb3);

    for (Entry<Double, SortBean> obj : sMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(obj.getKey());
    }

    }
}
```

**output:**

```
20.0
30.0
80.0
```